# Swift parameter's type not properly inferred?

Tags: swift, type-inference

`String` has the following initializers (amongst many):

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: Character)
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: UnicodeScalar)
```

so shouldn't the following work?

```
let str = String(count:8, repeatedValue:"*")    // Error: "Extra argument 'count' in call"
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to infer the type?!  Even if double quotes ***are*** strictly for String literals, both `Character` and `UnicodeScalar` conform to the `UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible` protocol. So what's happening here?

*Sure I could always do `repeatedValue:("*" as Character)` but then what's the point of having types inferred?!*

Comment: Maybe it's exactly because of this ambiguity? Since your string literal could be converted to match either method, which one should the compiler choose?

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem here (as @Thilo already mentioned) is the ambiguity of protocol conformance.

```
Character > ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible > UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible
UnicodeScalar > UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible
```

The compiler checks these protocols, but when it hits `UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible` it has no idea which initializer to choose.

You could make this easier by extending `String` with a unique initializer:

```
extension String {
    init(count: Int, repeatedCharacter: Character) {
        self.init(count: count, repeatedValue: repeatedCharacter)
    }
}

let str1 = String(count: 8, repeatedCharacter: "*")
println(str1)
```

or (although a bit over the top I think) a custom operator which makes it explicit that it's a `Character`:

```
postfix operator • {}
postfix func •(c: Character) -> Character { return c }

let str2 = String(count: 8, repeatedValue: "*"•)
println(str2)
```